# Как убрать вылет из программы из-за eval python

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

У меня есть код который при неправильном значении сказанного выводит ошибку. Например "365-7" работает верно но если данные типа "67 огурец" то вылетает и пишет unexpected EOF while parsing. Как сделать защиту от неправильных данных? Вот код

````
         while a == 1:
            voice_input = record_and_recognize_audio()
            os.remove("microphone-results.wav")
            print(voice_input)
            if voice_input == "стоп": a = 2
            if voice_input == "калькулятор":
                while b == 1:
                    print("Назовите пример:")
                    d = record_and_recognize_audio()
                    os.remove("microphone-results.wav")
                    if d == "выйти":
                        print("выход произошел")
                        break
                    print(d)
                    m = eval(d)
                    print("ответ:", m)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try:
    m = eval(d)
    print("ответ:", m)
except:
    print("что-то пошло не так")
```